# Currency drop down not showing when default currency set to GBP

Tags: currency

I set my default currency to GBP, after that my currency dropdown does not shows at all.  When I change it to CND it works. What could be the issue, please help.

Comment: how did you change it back then if it isn't shown? Do you have some more information?